# SQL order by DECODE and CASE return different data for the same conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, case, decode

I have a select query in ORACLE with order by and I've tried using both DECODE and CASE with the same conditions, but the ordering is done differently and can't understand why. I thought the problem is in NULL(null = null is unknown), but order by CASE gives the expected result.

This is the order by using DECODE:

```
order  by decode(seq_diff, abs(seq_diff), seq_diff, null) asc,
          decode(seq_diff, abs(seq_diff), null, seq_diff) desc,
          abs(dist_diff);
```

This is the order by using CASE:

```
order by  (case
             when seq_diff = abs(seq_diff) then seq_diff
             else null
           end) asc,
          (case
             when seq_diff = abs(seq_diff) then null
             else seq_diff
           end) desc,
           abs(dist_diff);
```

Below is the result for DECODE. (I included those decodes in the select to see the values).

For the positive values it sorts by seq_ref asc, but then for the negative values it seems to sort them also asc, not desc. And what is strange at row 28-29 it goes desc and then again asc.

[image: DECODE]

The order by CASE sorts the positive values by seq_ref asc and the negative values desc, as expected. This is the result for order by CASE:

[image: CASE]

Can somebody please explain why does this happen with decode?

Comment: Use the `case` expression if it works.

Comment: What is SEQ_DIFF column's datatype?

Comment: According to the [documentation of DECODE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions057.htm#SQLRF00631), DECODE returns VARCHAR2 datatype -so ABS(number) is converted to the string, while CASE EXPRESSION does not convert types. You should know the rest - the string "1111" is less that "2" while the number 1111 is grater than 2, so order by gives different results.

Comment: @Littlefoot  SEQ_DIFF is number

Comment: @krokodilo Could you please explain why does the decode return VARCHAR2 when the argument SEQ_DIFF is NUMBER? Shouldn't it return varchar2 when the expr and search are character data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked what the datatype was because sorting looked like sorting *strings*, not *numbers*.

Have a look at this. First, only one expression in order by clause:

```
SQL> with test (seq_diff) as
  2    (select -990 from dual union all
  3     select -610 from dual union all
  4     select -1350 from dual union all
  5     select -1340 from dual
  6    )
  7  select *
  8  from test
  9  order by decode(seq_diff, abs(seq_diff), seq_diff, null);

  SEQ_DIFF
----------
      -990
     -1340
     -1350
      -610

SQL>
```

How are they sorted? They aren't. According to sample data set, no `seq_diff` is equal to `abs(seq_diff)` so ordering moves to `null` which causes "randomly" ordered values. They aren't sorted at all.

---

Now, let's add another `decode` into order by:

```
SQL> with test (seq_diff) as
  2    (select -990 from dual union all
  3     select -610 from dual union all
  4     select -1350 from dual union all
  5     select -1340 from dual
  6    )
  7  select *
  8  from test
  9  order by decode(seq_diff, abs(seq_diff), seq_diff, null),
 10           decode(seq_diff, abs(seq_diff), null, seq_diff) desc;

  SEQ_DIFF
----------
      -990
      -610
     -1350
     -1340

SQL>
```

The first `decode` didn't do anything, as if it doesn't exist so we move on to the second `decode`. Again, according to data set, no `seq_diff` is equal to `abs(seq_diff)`, but this time it returns `seq_diff`. Documentation (as @krokodilko mentioned in their comment) says:

- The DECODE function returns a value that is the same datatype as the first result in the list.
- **If the first result is NULL, then the return value is converted to VARCHAR2.**

  - this is our case, so return value (`seq_diff`) is converted to `varchar2`
- If the first result has a datatype of CHAR, then the return value is converted to VARCHAR2.
- If no matches are found, the default value is returned.
- If default is omitted and no matches are found, then NULL is returned.

Once again: our case is the second one:

```
decode(seq_diff, abs(seq_diff), null, seq_diff)
                                ----
                                the first result is NULL
```

Therefore, `seq_diff` is converted to a string and values are sorted as such. Let's check that:

```
SQL> with test (seq_diff) as
  2    (select -990 from dual union all
  3     select -610 from dual union all
  4     select -1350 from dual union all
  5     select -1340 from dual
  6    )
  7  select *
  8  from test
  9  order by to_char(seq_diff) desc;

  SEQ_DIFF
----------
      -990
      -610
     -1350
     -1340

SQL>
```

See? The same result as we got with `order by decode(seq_diff, abs(seq_diff), null, seq_diff) desc;`

---

The final part of your `order by` clause is trivial (`abs(dist_diff)`), I guess there's no need to explain that.

---

That's why you got *strange* result with `DECODE`; actually, that's expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, it was really helpful!